# How can I determine if Java generic implements a particular interface?

Tags: java, generics

How can I determine if a Java generic implements a particular interface?

I have tried a few different approaches, but they all results in a "cannot find symbol ... variable T" error.

**First Attempt**

```
public abstract class AbstractClass<T> {
    public void doFoo() {
        if (T instanceof SomeInterface){
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

**Second Attempt**

```
public abstract class AbstractClass<T> {
    public void doFoo() {
        if (SomeInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(T)) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Comment: @Mena is right. And although I have no particular experience with generics in Java (I am a C# guy), I would suggest that you simply use type constraints to make the `if` always true. If you need multiple such `if`s, that would indicate some design flaw.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[You can't.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

#### Workaround  1

Add a constructor taking the class of the object.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass<T> {

    private Class<T> clazz;

    public AbstractClass(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public void doFoo() {
        if (clazz instanceof SomeInterface){
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

#### Workaround 2

Add a constraint to the type `T` with `T extends SomeInterface`, thereby restricting the type `T` to be a subtype of `SomeInterface`.

```
public abstract class AbstractClass<T extends SomeInterface> {
    public void doFoo() {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Put a bound on it.

```
public abstract class <T extends SomeInterface> { }
```

Then you're guaranteed that it will be *at least* `SomeInterface` when passed through as an argument to a method.

From your approach, there's no way to do it, since you don't reference an instance of `T` anywhere in your code.  If you added an argument to it, you'd be able to at least get further.

```
public void doFoo(T obj) { }
```

Comment: Unfortunately for me, T is not guaranteed to extend the interface that I am interested in.

Comment: That's a code smell to me...why would this class accept types which aren't homogeneous to the interface you're interested in?

Comment: In my case the class accepts T, and that implies that it accepts S (S extends T); If the class is of type S, then there is some additional/different code. Yes, this code may smell funny, but it is what I have to work with right now.